# Firefox - Remove Dotted Line Around Radio Button

Tags: css, firefox, radio-button

So I've seen the related posts on how to remove the dotted line around element in Firefox. But still no joy.

I've a unordered list with each `LI` containing a label and a radio button.  If I set the background color of the `LI` to any color then Firefox's dotted line appears around the radio button.  If I remove the background I get no dotted line. Strange.

I've tried using the following but still no luck.

```
input[type="radio"]:focus {border:0;}
input[type="radio"]:-moz-focusring {outline:none;}
```

Here's a JSFiddle of the problem (try removing/adding the background color on the LI):

http://jsfiddle.net/pSVD9/4/

Any ideas on how to remove the dotted line but keep the background color on the LI?

Comment: Sorry guys - even stranger - I closed FF4 and reopened - problem fixed. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens again, this should fix it:

```
input[type=radio],  select {
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: transparent !important;
    -moz-border-left-colors: transparent !important;
    -moz-border-right-colors: transparent !important;
    -moz-border-top-colors: transparent !important;
}
```

Although, it ends up adding some spacing to the top of it. It's negligible though.

*// edited for Tom Roggero* 
*// edited for iPadDeveloper2011*

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work for select.  Select isn't input[type=select].  Even when that is corrected it doesn't work.  You escaped a down vote because this is about radio buttons.

Comment: iPadDeveloper2011, you're right. I've updated my answer. Amazing to me how novice I was in 2011 :P